# Parallel processing of lists

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get my head around multiprocessing. I have a list, I divide it in two equally long parts, I sort them in two separate processes. I know that this part works because printing `saveto` gives me the two lists. But I can't access them because in the end I get two empty lists. Why can't I access what I want to be written to `l1` and `l2` and how do I do that?

```
import multiprocessing
import random


def sort(l, saveto):
    saveto = sorted(l)
    print saveto

if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = [int(100000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]

    listlen = len(l)
    halflist = listlen/2
    l1 = []
    l2 = []

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[0:halflist], l1))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[halflist:listlen], l2))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print l1
    print l2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to share data between processes

```
import multiprocessing
import random

def sort(l, queue):
    queue.put(sorted(l))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [int(100000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]

    listlen = len(l)
    halflist = listlen/2
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[0:halflist], queue))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[halflist:listlen], queue))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print queue.get()
    print queue.get()
```

**UPDATE:**

As it turned out putting the large amounts of data to Queue can cause a deadlock. This is [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues):

> **Warning**
>
> As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and
>   it has not used `JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread`), then that process
>   will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the
>   pipe.
>
> This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock
>   unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue
>   have been consumed. Similarly, if the child process is non-daemonic
>   then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries to join all its
>   non-daemonic children.
>
> Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue.

Fixed version:

```
import multiprocessing
import random

def sort(l, queue):
    queue.put(sorted(l))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [int(100000*random.random()) for i in range(10000)]

    listlen = len(l)
    halflist = listlen/2

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[0:halflist], queue))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[halflist:listlen], queue))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print queue.get()
    print queue.get()
```

Comment: They seem not to run simultaneously. `p2` seems to wait for `p1` to finish. How do I run them simultaneously?

Comment: They run simultaneously. If you add to sort function loop with `print` and `time.sleep()`, you can see it.

Comment: Ok, yes, you're right. But if I `print "done"` after `queue.put(sorted(l))`, `print "p1 started"` after `p1.start()` and `print "p2 started"` after `p2.start()` 
I always get:
`p1 started;
done;
p2 started;
done
`
So it ends up being processed in sequence anyway.