# multiprocessing: processes are run serially on Windows

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is a followup question of [Parallel processing of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885570/parallel-processing-of-lists)

I thought this is worth another question.

Task:

I have a list, I divide it in two equally long parts, I sort them in two separate processes.

```
import multiprocessing
import random

def sort(l, queue):
    queue.put(sorted(l))
    print "sorted"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [int(100000*random.random()) for i in range(100000)]

    listlen = len(l)
    halflist = listlen/2

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[0:halflist], queue))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sort, args=(l[halflist:listlen], queue))

    p1.start()
    print "p1 started"
    p2.start()
    print "p2 started"

    p1.join()
    print "p1 joined"
    p2.join()
    print "p2 joined"
```

If `sort` looks like this:

```
def sort(l, queue):
    time.sleep(5)
    print "sorted"
```

It works as expected. p1 and p2 are started immediatelly. If I do actually sort, the output is always this:

```
p1 started
sorted
p2 started
p1 joined
sorted
p2 joined
```

So `p2` always starts after `p1` finishes sorting. I can increase the number of elements in the list as much as I want (to 10M so that noone can say that sorting is just too fast), it does not change.

Why are they not processed in parallel and how do I fix this?

Using Win7x64, Python 2.7.12

In a Linux-VB with Python 2.7.12 I get the desired output, where `p1` and `p2` are started simultaneously. Must be a Windows issue. Whats wrong with Windows?

Comment: It *does* process in parallel. Sorting is just really fast in Python. Especially with only 50,000 items.

Comment: As I said, if I increase the number of random numbers to 10,000,000 or so it is not that fast anymore but `p2` is still started after `p1` is finished

Comment: you didn't mention 10 million anywhere. Why would you expect `p2` to start before `p1`? You start it after you start `p1`. Or did you mean that `p2` doesn't start until `p2` finishes?

Comment: Before the edit in the op it said `I can increase the number of elements in the list as much as I want`. Thats what I meant. I can increase it to 10M and it does not change. And the other thing I meant is that `p2` starts after `p1` finishes sorting which can take long with a high number of elements in the list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: CNR. I get "p1 started", "p2 started", "sorted", "sorted", "p1 joined", "p2 joined" with your exact code.

Comment: So you have `[int(100000*random.random()) for i in range(10000000)]`? Cause, that prints `p1 started\np2 started` (and then the rest) for me...

Comment: Yes. With `[int(100000*random.‌​random()) for i in range(10000000)]` always gives me `p1 started\nsorted\np2 started`. Maybe it is time to mention that I use Win7x64 and python 2.7.12

Comment: add another zero in your range. Do you still? And another zero? Cause apparently you have a really fast processor

Comment: I have an AMD FX8350. One process takes 17 seconds for sorting with 10M elements

Comment: btw 100M elements gives me a MemoryError.

Comment: Also, I tried to apply that concept to a more complex code which does more than just sorting (and takes longer) where I see the same effect of processes seemingly not running in parallel. The example in the OP is just a dumbed down version.

Comment: ...still, the example needs to be tested to actually reproduce the problem -- if it's simplified to the point where it doesn't, it's no good to anyone. I could see it being a platform-specific bug -- can you spin up a virtual machine and try to reproduce elsewhere, to narrow that down?

Comment: Well that simplified version in the OP actually does reproduce my problem. So, in a Linux Mint 18 VB I actually get what I want. So what's wrong with Windows?

Comment: I agree with Charles Duffy. See [this implementation](https://repl.it/CnVe/0) on Python 3.5.1 [GCC 4.8.2] on linux. It's a platform-specific bug. How many CPU/core do you have?

Comment: 4 physical cores with 8 threads.

Comment: I see now that this is platform specific. Can I work around it? Is this issue documented anywhere?

Comment: Does this have something to do with the `if __name__ == '__main__':` deal on Windows?